# The 'speed' displayed by tqdm is the instantaneous speed or the average speed?

Tags: python, tqdm

As the title says, I wonder the speed displayed in `tqdm` processing bar is instantaneous or average?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To display the speed, `tqdm` uses Exponential Moving Average Smoothing. From the [documentation](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/):

> smoothing: float, optional
>
> Exponential moving average smoothing factor
> for speed estimates (ignored in GUI mode). Ranges from 0 (average
> speed) to 1 (current/instantaneous speed) [default: 0.3].

You can therefore say that it's a mix of the two. As you already read above, you can choose one of these (by setting a 0/1 value) if you want to see the current or the average speed, but my opinion is that the default ratio is just fine.

Comment: As an important follow-up, a good rule of thumb is that `1/smoothing` is the "bandwidth" of the smoothing. In the case of `smoothing=0.25`, that means it's mainly using the last 4 iterations to calculate the average. Personally, I don't think that one-size-fits-all approach always works. What I like to use is `smoothing=50/total`, where `total` is the max number of iterations. This makes it so the average mainly uses the last 2% of the max number of iterations. This is much better smoothing behavior when there are many iterations (e.g. 10s of thousands), and a bandwidth of 3-4 isn't enough.